# User Profile Synchronization in Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile

How can I do User Profile Synchronization in SharePoint Foundation 2010? Eg. Scripting in Powershell (I know the Foundation Version do not have the User Profile Synchronization)

Comment: Not only that, there is no User Profile Service either. What are you "synchronizing" from and to?